# R dplyr strange filtering on data frame (reproducible code)

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

This seems like really odd behavior in dplyr filtering, could someone tell me where I am erring or if the below occurs on your machine as well. Thank you in advance.

When I try to filter a data frame using dplyr it works fine when using the original character string, but does not (at least on my machine) when pasting in or using a variable at all.

```
library(dplyr)

###Recreate data
country <- "ZAF"
df <- data.frame(iso3c=as.character("ZAF"), 
                   country=as.character("South Africa"), 
                   level=as.integer(4),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Problem is that these filter out the ZAF row, not keep it.

```
###Filters out the ZAF row, none of these work
df.nowork1 <- filter(df, iso3c==country)
df.nowork2 <- filter(df, iso3c==paste(country))
df.nowork3 <- filter(df, iso3c==paste0("'",country,"'"))
```

These do as I want them to do with a variable:

```
##Works 
df.works <- filter(df, iso3c=="ZAF")
df.works2 <- filter(df, iso3c==paste("ZAF"))
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question with your answer. If you found the solution yourself, you are welcome to answer below; otherwise you can chose another members answer as the one that helped you by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Questions that have been edited to include a solution may be rolled back to the previous state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this by specifying not to evaluate with the columns of dataset with the bang bang (`!!`)

```
df %>%
   filter(iso3c== !!country)
#  iso3c      country level
#1   ZAF South Africa     4
```

---

Or another way is to extract the object from `.GlobalEnv`

```
filter(df, iso3c== .GlobalEnv$country)
#  iso3c      country level
#1   ZAF South Africa     4
```

---

Here, the 'df' have a column named 'country', so within the enviornment, while specifying the 'country', it is checking the column and not the object outside the dataset

```
df %>%
    select(country)
#        country
#1 South Africa
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is this? Your solution works, but I'm confused as to why you wouldn't be able to use country as a variable in the original format

Comment: @NealBarsch  Because it will look with the  environment of 'df' where 'country' is a column and not the object `country` which you specified outside the environment of the dataset

Comment: What is the bang bang !! doing?

Comment: @NealBarsch  It evaluates the object and get the values from outside

Comment: I see. Because the column has the same name as the variable

Comment: @NealBarsch  Yes, otherwise, it would be checking the global environment and not getting stucked within the dataset env

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling sheepish on keeping a colname & variable the same name.

```
ctry <- country
works <- filter(df, iso3c==ctry)
```

Comment: I thought you intentionally kept it and wanted to find out how those situations can be evaluated.  Anyway, the `!!` would here too

Comment: Yeah I like the globals method, so I learned something in the process :)